# Fast Bitwise Sum in Python

Tags: python, numpy, bitwise-operators, binary-operators

Is there an efficient way to calculate sum of bits in each column over array in Python?

Example (Python 3.7 and Numpy 1.20.1):

1. Create numpy array with values 0 or 1

```
import numpy as np

array = np.array(
    [
     [1, 0, 1],   
     [1, 1, 1], 
     [0, 0, 1],    
    ]
)
```

2. Compress size by np.packbits

```
pack_array = np.packbits(array, axis=1)
```

3. Expected result: sum of bits in each position (column) without np.unpackbits to get the same as `array.sum(axis=0)`:

```
array([2, 1, 3])
```

I found just very slow solution:

```
dim = array.shape[1]
candidates = np.zeros((dim, dim)).astype(int)
np.fill_diagonal(candidates, 1)

pack_candidates = np.packbits(candidates, axis=1)

np.apply_along_axis(lambda c:np.sum((np.bitwise_and(pack_array, c) == c).all(axis=1)), 1, pack_candidates)
```

Comment: `apply_along_axis` is NOT as performance tool.

Comment: What is the use case? Why don't you want to use `unpackbits`?

Comment: Note that you can use `np.eye(dim, dtype=int)` to build candidates in a more simple way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `np.unpackbits` can be problematic if the input array is big since the resulting array can be **too big to fit in RAM**, and even if it does fit in RAM, this would be far from being efficient since the huge array have to be written and read from the (slow) main memory. The same thing apply for CPU caches: *smaller arrays can generally be computed faster*. Moreover, `np.unpackbits` have a quite big overhead for small arrays.

AFAIK, this is not possible to do this operation very efficiently in Numpy  while using a small amount of RAM (ie. using `np.unpackbits`, as pointed out by @mathfux). However, **Numba** can be used to speed up this computation, especially for small arrays. Here is the code:

```py
@nb.njit('int32[::1](uint8[:,::1], int_)')
def bitSum(packed, m):
    n = packed.shape[0]
    assert packed.shape[1]*8-7 <= m <= packed.shape[1]*8
    res = np.zeros(m, dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(m):
            res[j] += bool(packed[i, j//8] & (128>>(j%8)))
    return res
```

If you want a faster implementation, you can optimize the code by working on fixed-size tiles. However, this makes the code also more complex. Here is the resulting code:

```py
@nb.njit('int32[::1](uint8[:,::1], int_)')
def bitSumOpt(packed, m):
    n = packed.shape[0]
    assert packed.shape[1]*8-7 <= m <= packed.shape[1]*8
    res = np.zeros(m, dtype=np.int32)
    for i in range(0, n, 4):
        for j in range(0, m, 8):
            if i+3 < n and j+7 < m:
                # Highly-optimized 4x8 tile computation
                k = j//8
                b0, b1, b2, b3 = packed[i,k], packed[i+1,k], packed[i+2,k], packed[i+3,k]
                for j2 in range(8):
                    shift = 7 - j2
                    mask = 1 << shift
                    res[j+j2] += ((b0 & mask) + (b1 & mask) + (b2 & mask) + (b3 & mask)) >> shift
            else:
                # Slow fallback computation
                for i2 in range(i, min(i+4, n)):
                    for j2 in range(j, min(j+8, m)):
                        res[j2] += bool(packed[i2, j2//8] & (128>>(j2%8)))
    return res
```

Here are performance results on my machine:

```
On the example array:
Initial code:    62.90 us   (x1)
numpy_sumbits:    4.37 us   (x14)
bitSumOpt:        0.84 us   (x75)
bitSum:           0.77 us   (x82)

On a random 2000x2000 array:
Initial code:  1203.8  ms   (x1)
numpy_sumbits:    3.9  ms   (x308)
bitSum:           2.7  ms   (x446)
bitSumOpt:        1.5  ms   (x802)
```

The memory footprint of the Numba implementations is much better too (at least 8 times smaller).

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is no better option in numpy than `numpy.unpackbits`.

To be more clear, let's take another example:

```
array = np.array([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1], 
                  [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], 
                  [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
pack_array = np.packbits(array, axis=1)
dim = array.shape[1]
```

Now, `pack_array` is calculated in this way:

```
[[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0], [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] -> [174, 128]
[[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1], [1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] -> [255, 128]
[[0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]] -> [32, 0]
```

I've tested various algorithms and unpacking bits seems to be the fastest:

```
def numpy_sumbits(pack_array, dim):
    out = np.unpackbits(pack_array, axis=1, count=dim)
    arr = np.sum(out, axis=0)
    return arr

def manual_sumbits(pack_array, dim):
    arr = pack_array.copy()
    out = np.empty((dim//8+1) * 8, dtype=int)
    for i in range(8):
        out[7 - i%8::8] = np.sum(arr % 2, axis=0)
        arr = arr // 2
    return out[:dim]

def numpy_sumshifts(pack_array, dim):
    res = (pack_array.reshape(pack_array.size, -1) >> np.arange(8)) % 2
    res = res.reshape(*pack_array.shape, 8)
    return np.sum(res, axis=0)[:,::-1].ravel()[:dim]

print(numpy_unpackbits(pack_array, dim))
print(manual_unpackbits(pack_array, dim))
print(numpy_sumshifts(pack_array, dim))
>>>
[2 1 3 1 2 2 2 1 2]
[2 1 3 1 2 2 2 1 2]
[2 1 3 1 2 2 2 1 2]

%%timeit
numpy_sumbits(pack_array, dim)
>>> 3.49 ms ± 57.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
manual_sumbits(pack_array, dim)
>>> 10 ms ± 22.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%%timeit
numpy_sumshifts(pack_array, dim)
>>> 20.1 ms ± 97.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```